# Synchronise promises in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data, promise, synchronous

This might seem like an abuse of promises or an "you're doing it all wrong" question, if so please correct me. 
I ran into several points where I wanted to synchronize calls that by default were asynchronous in Ember.js. Here is a small example:

```
class service extends Ember.Object
  someProperty: null

  doSomething: ->
    #this.store was injected during initialisation
    this.store.find("someModel", someSelector).then((result) =>
      @someProperty = result.someField
      console.log "promise fulfilled"
  )
```

calling the following code:

```
service.doSomething()
console.log "this should be second"
```

will result in:

```
"this should be second"
"promise fulfilled"
```

which means that if someone calls the method and expects the property someProperty to be set after the call returns it will not be the case. The only way to synchronise that I would see is to call it like "service.doSomething().then(-> ....)". This would imply the caller needs to know that a promise is returned.

Is there any way to wait inside doSomething method until the promise is resolved and ONLY then return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This would imply the caller needs to know that a promise is returned

The caller obviously always needs to know what the function they are calling returns and even what parameters it takes. So you do not really have a problem here.

Comment: Fair enough, that is true. However you would expect certain methods to block until they have finished. The problem I generally see here is, that if you have like 4 or 5 calls that need to wait for the previous one to finish, you need to cascade "then" 3 or 4 times respectively, which just seems impractical. 

I was wondering if there is something in ember like in jquery ajax the "async: false" flag. Sometimes you just want to block until something has finished.

Comment: @Tom what do you mean by cascade? Using promises you will stay completely flat and especially using coffeescript you will have very little verbosity over code that would be synchronous

Comment: You're right, I did some more research and implemented a few test cases,.. I think this was more a matter of personal preference coming from a not-event-based background. When I thought about that case, I somehow overlooked that the "then" are not nested. Our solution is now to suffix methods that return promises, so anyone using the api knows that this method returns a promise and not a value. Thanks for the insigths!

On the other hand all implementations to synchronize promises or events felt like hacks or very ugly to me. The way JS handles threads just seems to not work well for blocking.

Answer (score 1):

As you already guessed, this is not a good idea. Javascript Development is all about **thinking and working asynchronously** and therefore the clients of your service should be exposed to the API of Promises. And i think that is a fair requirement, as promises are an easy to concept to learn to simplify asynchronous programming a lot.